# How to get the corresponding row based on the current date for tax calculation in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called tax calculation as follows

```
effective_date     c_gst     s_gst
01-03-2019         5%        5%
01-08-2019         8%        8%
01-05-2020         9%        9%
```

how to get the row based on the current date ie. 19-02-2020, this is for tax calculation the effective date is used to search the tax %. the row has to >= to the effective date.

The output should be:

```
01-08-2019    8%    8%
```

Comment: select ... where date condition order by ... limit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the row with the latest date that is less than or equal to `'2020-02-19'`:

```
select * 
from tablename 
where effective_date = (
  select max(effective_date) 
  from tablename 
  where effective_date <= '2020-02-19'
)
```